# ACL filtering，can't send transaction

Tags: tezos-client, rpc, transactions, docker, baking-node

I sent the transaction report after upgrading from 10.0~ RC3 to V11.0.0,Now I can't send a transaction,what should i do

start node: ./tezos-docker-manager.sh start --rpc-port 8732

ubuntu@VM-0-13-ubuntu:/home$ /data/xtz/tezos-docker-manager.sh client  transfer 0.623456 from yhb_test_1111  to *******************  --burn-cap 0.257
Disclaimer:
The  Tezos  network  is  a  new  blockchain technology.
Users are  solely responsible  for any risks associated
with usage of the Tezos network.  Users should do their
own  research to determine  if Tezos is the appropriate
platform for their needs and should apply judgement and
care in their network interactions.

Node is bootstrapped.
Rpc request failed:

- meth: POST
- uri: http://node:8732/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/simulate_operation
- error: The server doesn't authorize this endpoint (ACL filtering).
  Fatal error:
  transfer simulation failed
  ubuntu@VM-0-13-ubuntu:/home$

Answer (score 2):

For me it works with the following parameters:

```
--rpc-addr 0.0.0.0:8732 --allow-all-rpc 0.0.0.0:8732
```

First one makes RPC listen for connections on any interface, and the second fixes ACL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow RPC functionality. Check also [the documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/node-configuration.html) on the new ACLs.

See if this works for you:

`./tezos-docker-manager.sh start --rpc-port 8732 --allow-all-rpc 0.0.0.0:8732`

Comment: It still doesn't work，report the same error
The startup parameters in the in docker-compose.yml :    command: tezos-node --net-addr :9732 --allow-all-rpc 0.0.0.0:8732 --network mainnet

Comment: You're going to have to play around with those settings unfortunately as those ACL flags are the only way to get the RPC working correctly.